# Offer embed code when height and width are not known

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have a site which allows users to list/add things. Images mainly.

I want to offer an embed service for what they list/add, so they can include their own content on their own pages/blogs if they choose to.

**QUESTION** how to get around the height and width issue of an iframe?

I want to offer a width setting of 100% so whichever container they add the code to, it fits (there is size code in the page so alignment/image sizing etc will be ok that way)

I also want the height to be 100% of the content they embed.

So using something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>     
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');       
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.src = 'URL OF CONTENT';       
    iframe.width = 'How to say 100%';
    iframe.height = 'How to say overflow:auto';
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this?